# Event for clear input in Legacy Edge (version 44)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a simple html input field

```
<input id="query" type="text" oninput="QueryInput(this.value)"  onchange="QueryChange(this.value)">
```

and I've tried different ways to capture the clear (an `x` shows up in the right of the textbox when I enter with mouse to type something there) event in Edge (my version is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0).

```
<p id="demo_typed"></p>
<p id="demo_typing"></p>
<p id="demo_oninput"></p>
<p id="demo_onchange"></p>

<script>
function QueryChange(query) {
  document.getElementById("demo_onchange").innerHTML = `You changed to ${query}`;
}
function QueryInput(query) {
  document.getElementById("demo_oninput").innerHTML = `You inputted ${query}`;
}
document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  document.getElementById("demo_typing").innerHTML = `You are typing ${event.target.value}`;
});
document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  document.getElementById("demo_typed").innerHTML = `You typed ${event.target.value}`;
});
</script>
```

but none of them reacts on the clear event (except for the change that can be triggered after it, when the mouse leaves the input): is it not doable?

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
function QueryChange(query) {
  document.getElementById("demo_onchange").innerHTML = `You changed to ${query}`;
}
function QueryInput(query) {
  document.getElementById("demo_oninput").innerHTML = `You inputted ${query}`;
}
document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  document.getElementById("demo_typing").innerHTML = `You are typing ${event.target.value}`;
});
document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  document.getElementById("demo_typed").innerHTML = `You typed ${event.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The question is specific to Legacy Edge, not the newer Chromium-based Edge.</p>

<input id="query" type="text" oninput="QueryInput(this.value)"  onchange="QueryChange(this.value)">

<p id="demo_typed"></p>
<p id="demo_typing"></p>
<p id="demo_oninput"></p>
<p id="demo_onchange"></p>
```

Comment: BTW Also Internet Explorer (for example version 1909 on Windows 10) has that 'x' to clear the input, but the slightly modified version for IE does work, and both `input` `addEventListener` and `oninput` do react on the clear event.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you need to support Legacy Edge? Users have to try *really hard* not to upgrade to Chromium Edge, so there should be virtually no users of it in the wild...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is the version I find installed in my corporate laptop (it's quite a big company in Italy with a large ICT dept. I don't know about the version they install in the offices abroad, to be honest). So in my company I guess there are a lot of intranet users. But ok, it is not a real problem, we can use chrome (or firefox), just to know.

Comment: Interesting! I'm surprised your ICT department is suppressing the Chromium Edge update.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting, I didn't notice it. I think I can ask someone of my colleagues why... I will update you when/if I receive an answer from them about the version they install

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious, it doesn't change or invalidate the question. (BTW, I think I've seen this question before somewhere, but I'm not finding it here on SO. Sadly I think the answer was "no, there's no event.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm happy to accept it, if that's the answer. (will let you know anyway when I receive a reply from my colleagues)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder They've confirmed we're rolling out the update for all our users in the next months, so everything ok ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a

> no, there's no event.

answer, as T.J. Crowder suggested in his comment, the best advice I found is to hide the Edge clear button with a style

```
<style>
input::-ms-clear {
    display: none
}
</style>
```

and possibly add my custom clear button.

For example, if the input is wrapped in a

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
```

the cleanse could be implemented via a form reset and running all the needed reset actions

```
function clear_input() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  document.getElementById("demo_typed").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("demo_typing").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("demo_oninput").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("demo_onchange").innerHTML = '';
}

document.getElementById("myBtnClear").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clear_input();
});
```

### Alternative solution, without hiding the Edge clear

Otherwise, as proposed in the [Angular github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26307#issuecomment-493057465) and adapted here to vanilla Javascript by me, one could subscribe the `mouseup` event as a workaround and intercept the Edge clear as follows:

```
document.getElementById("query").addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  beforeVal = event.target.value;
  setTimeout(() => {
    afterVal =event.target.value;
    if (beforeVal !== '' && afterVal === '') {
        clear_input();
    }
  }, 1);
  
});
```